# No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am using intellij and my M2 and M2_HOME are set and are in .bash_profile, however I have this error :

No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog       or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system

any idea why it does not work with environment variable ?

Comment: GUI apps don't read `.bash_profile`. If you are on Mac, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891.

Comment: It should work if you add `M2_HOME` to `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, it works after checking the link you mentioned, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 67):

Selecting "Bundled Maven" instead of "Maven wrapper" fixed the issue for me.
[image]

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, it also worked for me. You know why?

Comment: Is this the accepted answer?

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 17):

On Mac (I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.1, IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2).

Choose <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> , choose **Build, Execution, Deployment**, choose **Build Tools**, then press **Maven**

[image]

then set **Maven home directory:** correctly

for example: `/Users/donhuvy/Documents/program_files/apache-maven-3.3.9`

Answer (score 3):

Check your `File-->settings-->Maven`, Maven directory home which should points to your maven home installed in your computer.
Then, create a new `M2_Home` in your system environment which is also your maven home, and then add `%M2_Home%\bin` to your path.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.
I think the reason for the maven auto update

There are two ways to solve the problem.:

1. Change the Maven path and Maven setting file path.(I use it.)
   **File**->**preferences**->**Build,Excution,Deployment...**->**Build Tool** -> Maven.you can reset it.
2. Reset local computer environment variable for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on **configuration dialog** in the error message, the **Maven home path** should not be set to **C:...\apache-maven\bin** but to simply **C:...\apache-maven**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).