# Intellij - No valid Maven installation found when configured to use Maven Wrapper

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-wrapper

I've upgraded my IntelliJ Community from 2021.1 to 2021.2 today and now I'm getting the following error when trying to run maven commands:

```
No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system.
```

But it's correctly configured to use Maven Wrapper:
[image: Maven Configuration]

My `.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties` is as follow:

```
distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip
wrapperUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/takari/maven-wrapper/0.5.6/maven-wrapper-0.5.6.jar
```

What am I supposed to do in order to keep using Maven Wrapper? Or is it a possible bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug: [IDEA-258757](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258757) Cannot start tasks with maven wrapper

**UPD:** This is fixed in versions 2021.3+

Comment: Updating Intellij did not resolve the issue for me, I used the bundled maven wrapper as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68712395/3944040